# Mocking static class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a method in a class that instantiate a static class instance and call operation on it.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod() {
       MyClass.MyStaticClass myStaticClassInstance =
          new MyClass.MyStaticClass( arg1, arg2, arg3 );
       myStaticClassInstance.callSomeMethod();
    }
}

public class MyClass {

   public static class MyStaticClass {

      public MyStaticClass( Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3 ) {
      }

      public void callSomeMethod() {
      }
   }
}
```

How to mock static class instanciation, so that I could mock `callSomeMethod()` without going through the static class constructor ?

Comment: you should not instantiate `MyStaticClass` in `SomeClass` at all in the first place. You should use *dependency inversion* to inject an instances of `MyStaticClass` into the instance of `SomeClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `PowerMock` by mocking instantiation of your static inner class. This can be done by preparing the class that will actually instantiate your static inner class so here it will be the class in which you have the method `someMethod()` defined.

Assuming that `someMethod()` is defined into the class `MyOtherClass` and returns nothing, your test class would be something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // The runner of PowerMock
@PrepareForTest(MyOtherClass.class) // the class to prepare
public class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // The mock of your static inner class to return
        MyClass.MyStaticClass mock = Mockito.mock(MyClass.MyStaticClass.class);
        // Mock the call of callSomeMethod()
        PowerMockito.doAnswer(
            new Answer<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    // Do something here as new implementation of callSomeMethod
                    System.out.println("My new Answer");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        ).when(mock).callSomeMethod();
        // Return your mock in case we instantiate MyClass.MyStaticClass in 
        // the prepared class with any arguments  
        PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClass.MyStaticClass.class)
            .withArguments(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any(), Matchers.any())
            .thenReturn(mock);

        // The code that will call someMethod
        MyOtherClass mc = new MyOtherClass();
        mc.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Assuming that my class `MyClass` looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static class MyStaticClass {
        public MyStaticClass(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) {
            System.out.println("Called constructor");
        }

        public void callSomeMethod() {
            System.out.println("callSomeMethod");
        }
    }
}
```

And my class `MyOtherClass` looks like this:

```
public class MyOtherClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        MyClass.MyStaticClass myStaticClassInstance = new MyClass.MyStaticClass(
            new Object(), new Object(), new Object()
        );
        myStaticClassInstance.callSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

If I launch my test, I get as expected:

```
My new Answer
```

Instead of what I should get by default:

```
Called constructor
callSomeMethod
```

More details about [how to constructions of new objects](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects).

Comment: Yes it is clear, but it is not working.  The execution is going inside the constructor of the static class when doing `new MyClass.MyStaticClass( arg1, arg2, arg3 );` which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm not instanciating the static class inside the public class where it is defined, that is the difference with your code.

Comment: I change `@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)` with `@PrepareForTest(SomeClass .class)` and it is working.  Thank you for you code example, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simpler tool for mocking things that are normally 'non-mockable' at https://github.com/iirekm/misc/tree/master/ajmock

Your code can look like:

```
    public class MyClassTest {

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    MyClass.MyStaticClass mock = Mockito.mock(MyClass.MyStaticClass.class);
    when(() -> mock.callSomeMethod()).thenAnswer(() -> ...);

    when(() -> new MyClass.MyStaticClass(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(mock);

    // The code that will call someMethod
    MyOtherClass mc = new MyOtherClass();
    mc.someMethod();
}
```

}

```